# Using AND to find multiple records

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am using this Select statement to run this query in both Access and Excel VBA to open multiple records but having no luck:

```
Select * From tmDates where (Barcode = 100504339) and (Barcode = 100509738)
```

If I search one barcode it will work but not for two or more. Barcode is a PK in the table not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rogelio

Comment: use `or` instead of `and`;because `barcode` would not have 2 values in one row.

Comment: You should use:
`Select * From tmDates where (Barcode = 100504339) or (Barcode = 100509738)`

Comment: The query engine looks at each row separately, and asks one or more questions based on your `where` clause.  Because your where clause has two terms joined with `AND`, the answer to *both* questions must be yes.  The first question is "Is the barcode 100504339?"; the second is "Is the barcode 100509738"?  It is impossible for any row to exist where the answer to both questions is "yes"; you are therefore guaranteed to have an empty result set.

Comment: ahhh I see what your mean. Ok AND is the wrong operator to use. I'm going to use in as the members have suggested.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You want `or`, but the normal way to write such a query is using `in`:

```
Select *
From tmDates
where Barcode IN (100504339, 100509738)
```

Note:  if `Barcode` is a string, then enclose the constants in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `OR` instead of `AND`.  SQL searches per-row, and on a single record, `Barcode` cannot be *both* of the values at the same time.

You should use this instead:

```
Select    * 
From      tmDates 
Where     (Barcode = 100504339) 
Or        (Barcode = 100509738)
```

Alternatively, you can use `IN` and specify the values:

```
Select    * 
From      tmDates 
Where     Barcode In (100504339, 100509738)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Barcode is a single column and you want to get one entry of the table matching this Barcode, you should use [...] where (Barcode = ...) OR (Barcode = ...) else the statement is always false and it does'nt select anything.